# Check recursively if array is sorted up on the even indexes

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to write a recursive function which checks whether the given array is sorted upwards on the even indexes. for example I have an array of `size 5`. and the numbers are `1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ,5`. It will `return 1` because `arr[0] < arr[2] < arr[4]`.

The problem on that line:

```
if (i >= arr[isEven]) return 1; //Sorted
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int SortedUpDown(int arr, int num);

int main()
{
    int sizeOfArr = 0, i = 0,*arr, num = 0, checkIfSorted = -1;
    printf("Enter the size of the array : \n");
    scanf("%d", &sizeOfArr);
    printf("Enter %d numbers to the array \n: ", sizeOfArr);
    arr = (int *)malloc(sizeOfArr * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < sizeOfArr; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        *(arr + i) = num;
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    checkIfSorted = SortedUpDown(*arr,sizeOfArr);
    getch();

    return 0;
}

int SortedUpDown(int *arr, int num)
{
    int i = 0, isEven = 0;
    if (num % 2 == 0) isEven = num - 2; //if The array is even, (for example arr[6] then check 0,1,2,3,4,5 only 0,2,4)
    else isEven = num - 1; //if the array is odd, (for example arr[7] then check 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 only 0,2,4,6)
    if (i >= arr[isEven]) return 1; //Sorted
    if (arr[i] > arr[i + 2]) return 0; //Not sorted
    return i += 2, SortedUpDown(arr, num); //Advance i by 2.
}
```

Error thrown:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00AE18BC in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000011.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

**Edit:** I want to check now if it is going downwards for odd indexes and it does not work, here's my code:

I've got 2 questions:

1. Why it doesn't work?

   2. Can you help me write those 2 functions in one function, which means, it will check Up on even and Down on odd indexes simultanously?

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <stdlib.h> 
> #include <conio.h>  
>
> int SortedDown(int *arr, int num); 
> int SortedUp(int *arr, int num);
>
> int main(void)
> {
>   int sizeOfArr = 0, i = 0, *arr, num = 0, checkIfSortedDown = -1, checkIfSortedUp = -1;
>   printf("Enter the size of the array : \n");
>   scanf("%d", &sizeOfArr);
>   printf("Enter %d numbers to the array \n: ", sizeOfArr);
>   arr = (int *)malloc(sizeOfArr * sizeof(int));
>   for (i = 0; i < sizeOfArr; i++)
>   {
>       scanf("%d", arr + i);
>       printf("%d ", arr[i]);
>   }
>   puts("");
>   checkIfSortedDown = SortedDown(arr, sizeOfArr);
>   checkIfSortedUp = SortedUp(arr, sizeOfArr);
>   if (checkIfSortedDown && checkIfSortedUp)
>       puts("Sorted");
>   else
>       puts("Not Sorted");
>   free(arr);
>   getch();
>
>   return 0;
> }
>
> int SortedDown(int *arr, int num) {
>   --num;//size to last index
>   if (num % 2 != 0) //if index is not even
>       --num;
>   if (num <= 0)
>       return 1;//Sorted
>   else if (arr[num - 2] > arr[num])
>       return 0;//Not sorted
>   else
>       return SortedDown(arr, num - 2 + 1);//+1 : last index to size
> }
>
> int SortedUp(int *arr, int num) {
>   --num;//size to last index
>   if (num % 2 == 0)
>       --num;
>   if (num <= 0)
>       return 1;//Sorted
>   else if (arr[num - 2] < arr[num])
>       return 0;//Not sorted
>   else
>       return SortedUp(arr, num - 2 + 1);//+1 : last index to size
> }
> ```

Comment: Looks like one of your cases is reading past the end of the array: `if (arr[i] > arr[i + 2]) return 0; //Not sorted`

Comment: @KristopherMicinski And I think the line before that needs to be changed to if (i >= isEven) return 1; //Sorted

Comment: @KristopherMicinski What do you think about the edit?

Comment: I for one will need some time just to figure out that `return` statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //need this header
#include <conio.h>  //not standard

int SortedUpDown(int *arr, int num);//prototype to match implementation 

int main(void)
{
    int sizeOfArr = 0, i = 0, *arr, num = 0, checkIfSorted = -1;
    printf("Enter the size of the array : \n");
    scanf("%d", &sizeOfArr);
    printf("Enter %d numbers to the array \n: ", sizeOfArr);
    arr = (int *)malloc(sizeOfArr * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < sizeOfArr; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", arr + i);
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    puts("");
    checkIfSorted = SortedUpDown(arr, sizeOfArr);//pass arr, not *arr
    if(checkIfSorted)
        puts("Sorted");
    else
        puts("Not Sorted");
    free(arr);
    getch();

    return 0;
}

int SortedUpDown(int *arr, int num){
    --num;//size to last index
    if (num % 2 != 0)
        --num;
    if(num <= 0)
        return 1;//Sorted
    else if (arr[num-2] > arr[num])
        return 0;//Not sorted
    else
        return SortedUpDown(arr, num-2+1);//+1 : last index to size
}
```

Comment: Just an insignificant *warning* correction, `unused variable ‘num’` in `main()`. Well done.

Comment: Ah! yes. That's my fault　(reduce code).　He/She might go back.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'll check the code asap. Thank you so much! P.S. from a quick look, I have many fund. mistakes I need to get sorted. thanks for the "\\" addition.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Do you have any idea how can I edit that function so I can check whether on the odd indexes the array is going down? arr[1] > arr[3] > arr[5] and so on..

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Do you have any idea how can I edit that function so I can check whether on the odd indexes the array is going down? arr[1] > arr[3] > arr[5] and so on

Comment: I think it would be very similar function.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you run into an infinite loop when you call SortedUpDown() from within SortedUpDown() since i is set to zero on every invocation.

Try using static to preserve the value of 'i';

```
static int i = 0;
```

EDIT:

In addition I fixed a few issues starting with the fn declaration as a pointer.

```
int SortedUpDown(int *arr, int num);
```

And calling it as such:

```
checkIfSorted = SortedUpDown(arr,sizeOfArr);
```

Below is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int SortedUpDown(int *arr, int num);

int main()
{
    int sizeOfArr = 0, i = 0,*arr, num = 0, checkIfSorted = -1;
    printf("Enter the size of the array : \n");
    scanf("%d", &sizeOfArr);
    printf("Enter %d numbers to the array \n: ", sizeOfArr);
    arr = (int *)malloc(sizeOfArr * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < sizeOfArr; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        *(arr + i) = num;
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    checkIfSorted = SortedUpDown(arr,sizeOfArr);
    printf("\ndone %d\n",checkIfSorted);
    //getch();

    return 0;
}

int SortedUpDown(int *arr, int num)    
{
    static int i = 0;
    if (i >= num - 1) return 1;
    if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) return 0;
    return i++, SortedUpDown(arr, num);
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, even for the code in the "edit:" section.

Comment: works for me but I did some other clean up that I thought wasn't required. let me post all edits

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: Are you sure? I don't want to insult you, but are you sure you applied `static` to the right `i`? If so, then try preparing [a minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and posting that.

Comment: the 'i' within the SortedUpDown .. I'll post the whole code, it's working for me (under linux, so I had to change a couple of #include directives)

Comment: @AssafStoler Do you have any idea how can I edit that function so I can check whether on the odd indexes the array is going down? arr[1] > arr[3] > arr[5] and so on